# Fix short variables warnings in pylint

Tags: pylint

I want to have a `~/.pylintrc` that accepts all short variables of 3 characters or less without telling me they don't conform to style. Also accept all words in uppercase with underscores without saying it doesn't conform to snake_case naming style

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add

```
disable=invalid-name
```

to my ~/.pylintrc to remove the convention message C0103. I add this to my ~/.pylintrc because I use with statements to open files and usually keep the temporary filehandle name as f without complaint. Example:

```
with open('path.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```